# Ninject raising TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, ninject, asp.net-2.0

I am using Ninject 1.5 with my .Net 2.0 web application.  My local dev machine had no problem running the application, but once I deploy it onto a testing server, all I get is a big yellow saying that -

> "Method 'Ninject.Core.Infrastructure.TypedCollection '2.Add' on
>   'Ninject.Core.Parameters.ParameterCollection' from assembly
>   'Ninject.Core, Version=1.5.0.0,...' tried to implicitly implement an
>   interface method with weaker type parameter constraints."

My code is throwing this exception when it is creating the Ninject kernel and loads my StandardModules.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have some DLL version mismatch issue. Where did you get the DLL(s) ? (rhetorical)

Why not use any of the builds from more recently this decade and take andvantage of massive amounts of real world battering the framework has recieved since the v2 days - use v2 - it supports .NET 2 perfectly.

If you have a specific reason for using that version, it doesnt hurt, but using .NET 2 isnt it.

Comment: According to ninject's website, only 1.5 supports .Net 2.0  http://ninject.org/download.html

Comment: @Dan appleyard - Mea culpa, yes 2.0 is a big pile of LINQ soup. Temporarily forgot about that 3.5 thing that happened between 2.0 and 4.0! I'll leave the post here as a warning to other people jumping to concusions, though to be fair it desrves a -1 really..